# Getting bitmap of gridview returning wrong

Tags: android, gridview

I am getting bitmap of gridview using this line of code

```
aftershu = Bitmap.createBitmap(image_grid.getDrawingCache());
```

But when i get this i'm not getting the current view of gridview i'm getting one view before the current view .

Here is my code

```
image_grid.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


image_grid.buildDrawingCache(true);
   // Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mGridView.getDrawingCache());
    beforeshu= Bitmap.createBitmap(image_grid.getDrawingCache());
    Bitmap x=getResizedBitmap(beforeshu,200,200);
    b1.setImageBitmap(x);

    Collections.shuffle(smallimages);
    image_grid.setAdapter(new SmallImageAdapter(this, smallimages));
    //  image_grid.setAdapter(new SmallImageAdapter());

    image_grid.setNumColumns((int) Math.sqrt(smallimages.size()));
    image_grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        int firstclick;
    int counter=0;
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
            counter++;
            if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                firstclick = position;
                Bitmap data1 = smallimages.get(position);

            } else {


                Bitmap swapImage = smallimages.get(position);
                smallimages.set(position, smallimages.get(firstclick));
                smallimages.set(firstclick, swapImage);

                image_grid.invalidateViews();


            }
            aftershu = Bitmap.createBitmap(image_grid.getDrawingCache());
        }

    });
```

this beforeshu is getting correct bitmap of before shuffling but aftershu bitmap is returning the image view before last swap in grid view

I inserted this line after the onclick i.e when clicking the checkresult but it returns always the beforeshu bitmap.

my output left image is before shuffle right image is the bitmap i get when i click checkresult

[image: [1]:]

So how to get the bitmap of current view of gridview i.e.when i click checkresult button

Answer (score 0):

I solved by this method from stackoverflow

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
           Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
           Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
           Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
           if (bgDrawable!=null)
               bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
           else
               canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
           view.draw(canvas);

           return bitmap;
       }
```

i passed gridview to this method and got the current bitmap